# static_allocator to make static_vector from std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, static, c++20, allocator

I want to implement `static_vector`, i.e. container like `std::vector`, but having fixed size storage statically allocated (reserved) on construction and never exceeded during its lifetime.

Because allocator object is a data member of almost every (except `std::array`) container in C++ standard library, I decided to make raw storage a part of allocator. In the case `std::vector` virtually will contain whole storage it use.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <new>

#include <cassert>

template<size_t N>
struct make
{
    template<typename T>
    struct static_allocator
    {
        using value_type = T;
        
        using propagate_on_container_copy_assignment = std::false_type;
        using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::false_type;
        using propagate_on_container_swap = std::false_type;
     
        [[nodiscard]] T * allocate(std::size_t n) 
        {
            if (n != N)
                throw std::bad_alloc();
            return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_storage);
        }
        
        void deallocate(T * p, std::size_t n) noexcept
        { 
            assert(p == reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_storage));
            assert(n == N); 
        }

    private:
        std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T) * N, alignof(T)>  m_storage;
    };
};
 
template<size_t N, typename T>
bool operator == (const typename make<N>::template static_allocator<T> & lhs, const typename make<N>::template static_allocator<T> & rhs) { return &lhs == &rhs; }

template<size_t N, typename T>
bool operator != (const typename make<N>::template static_allocator<T> & lhs, const typename make<N>::template static_allocator<T> & rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }

#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int, make<10>::static_allocator<int>> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }
    auto u = std::move(v);
    std::copy(std::cbegin(u), std::cend(u), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

On destruction [the code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GLDQWA8Kv7TgTB6r) gives an error:

```
 prog.exe: prog.cc:29: void make<10>::static_allocator<int>::deallocate(T *, std::size_t) [N = 10, T = int]: Assertion `p == reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_storage)' failed.
```

The cause of the error is that during move construction of `std::vector` underlying allocator is also move constructed. There is postcondition for allocators `a` and `a1` of type `A`: `a == a1` after `A a1(std::move(a));`, which breaks whole endeavour.

The postcondition makes allocators in Standard Library too restricted, I believe. Is there chance would it be removed in the future? Is there strong theoretical reason to keep this restriction in the Standard?

Comment: IIRC, moving a vector is not supposed to change the addresses of the elements of the vector. This is a legitimate requirement, and static_vector legitimately fails to meet it.

Comment: What do you mean by "statically allocated"? If the storage is part of the instance of the type (ie: `sizeof(static_vector<...>)` changes with the size, so the size is part of the type), then you shouldn't have an `allocator` at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I mean that storage is a part of the instance of the type (data member). My intention was to adapt `std::vector` using just allocator.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation of what you possibly try to achieve.
https://github.com/alekstheod/static_vector

Basically store the array -> data inside your own definition of the vector and replace the allocator to use this data when allocating a memory.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Rephrased the answer...

Answer (score -1):

Based on your saying:

> I want to implement static_vector, i.e. container like std::vector, but having fixed size storage statically allocated (reserved) on construction and never exceeded during its lifetime.

Looks like a static array would be the best, since you dont need to exceed the size ever, just do something like

```
int arr[your_size];
```

and intialize what you need to intialize, set all the other values to `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN`.

Comment: Really it would be a first step to `small_vector`. But now I know this was a wrong way.